# How to reuse downloaded rosdistro repo in bloom-release?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I do new releases of my packages, one of the longest taking phases is cloning the rosdistro repo over and over.

How can I tell `bloom-release` the path to a locally cloned repo which it'd use instead of cloning?

Another way to speed up the process would be to make only a shallow clone of the repo, which should be also IMO ok.

Can I achieve one of the two improvements with existing bloom?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329652/how-to-reuse-downloaded-rosdistro-repo-in-bloom-release?/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2019-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bloom doesn't currently have the ability to use an existing clone of rosdistro. But if you were interested you could implement the feature and contribute a pull request. There was a pull request to use shallow clones but the shallow clone couldn't be used to push local changes upstream so that approach was abandoned https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/538

Opening the pull request without a local clone using the GitHub repository content API would also be an efficient way to push the updates but it would need to be implemented as GitHub-specific behavior. Then again, the pull request creation behavior is GitHub-specific already so that may not preset a challenge at all.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2020-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2